# Count Inversions using Merge Sort in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, mergesort

So I understand the general idea behind counting inversions in an array using merge sort. You recursively count the number of inversions in the left subarray and right subarray during the merging process.

Here is some code I wrote to do that.

```
int count_and_merge(vector<int>& array, const vector<int>& left_subarray, const vector<int>& right_subarray) {

    vector<int> merged {};

    array.clear();

    int left_index = 0, right_index = 0, sorted_index = 0;
    int inversions = 0;

    while(left_index < left_subarray.size() and right_index < right_subarray.size()) {

        if(left_subarray[left_index] <= right_subarray[right_index])
            array.push_back(left_subarray[left_index++]);
        else {

            array.push_back(right_subarray[right_index++]);
            inversions += left_subarray.size() - left_index;

        }

    }

    while(left_index < left_subarray.size()) array.push_back(left_subarray[left_index++]);
    while(right_index < right_subarray.size()) array.push_back(right_subarray[right_index++]);

    return inversions;

}

int count_inversions_and_sort(vector<int>& array) {

    if(array.size() <= 1) return 0;

    int n = array.size();

    vector<int> left_subarray(array.begin(), array.begin() + n / 2),
                right_subarray(array.begin() + n / 2, array.end());
    
    int left_subarray_inversions  = count_inversions_and_sort(left_subarray),
        right_subarray_inversions = count_inversions_and_sort(right_subarray);

    return left_subarray_inversions + right_subarray_inversions + count_and_merge(array, left_subarray, right_subarray); 

}
```

What I'm having difficulty understanding is why it's necessary to clear the array in the `count_and_merge` function before appending elements to it? Is there another way to do it without clearing the array? I ask because I'm used to writing merge sort with `array[sorted_index++] = left_subarry[left_index++]`

Comment: The algorithms are ultimately identical. clear will reset the content size counter (and fire destructors for anything requiring it, which in this case is nothing), but the *reserve* remains. Therefore, your clear + push_back sequence is effectively the same as noclear + indexed-assignment. The purpose of that provided vector it to *prevent* a from-scratch place to perform the targeted merge, much akin to pre-allocating the N-space temp storage of a simple mergesort from the outset, then passing it down the line as the merge progresses.

Comment: Did you try commenting out that line to see what happens? Such an experiment is not conclusive (you should not use it to support conclusions), but it can be informative (lead you to conclusions that you verify through other means).

Answer (score 1):

> Why it's necessary to clear the array in the `count_and_merge` function before appending elements to it?

It is necessary in the shown example since you append elements after `array`. However, you want `array` to remain the same length but be sorted.

> I ask because I'm used to writing merge sort with `array[sorted_index++] = left_subarry[left_index++]`

I don't see a reason why you can't use that instead of `std::vector::push_back()`. The original content in `array` isn't really important since the needed information is contained in `left_subarray` and `right_subarray`. Therefore, you can directly overwrite to `array`. If fact, if you use this implementation, you don't even need `std::vector::clear()` beforehand.